# Changing the frequency of log axis ticks in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, axis-labels

I'm using pylab and set the y-axis to log scale. I specified the y limit:

```
f.gca().set_ylim(10.**(-0.3),10.**(0.3))
```

But the figure I get only displays one tick at 10^0:
[image]

How do I change the tick frequency to make the y-axis display 10x more ticks labels?

Answer (score 1):

```
ax.locator_params(axis='y',nbins=10)
```

should do it

Edit: I apologize, that sets the *number* of ticks.  The additional problem here is that there is one **major** tick and many **minor** ticks.  Matplotlib is formatting the major tick labels but not the minor ones.  It does the same thing for your xaxis, but fortuitously you have 4 major ticks there.

You can either redefine what are 'major' ticks (there's a number of approaches for this), or tell matplotlib that you want it to format labels for the minor ticks as well.

```
formatter = ax.get_major_formatter()
ax.set_minor_formatter(formatter)
```

You can probably figure out how to get that looking like you want.

Were I you, I would probably try and work on what it considers 'major' ticks, though.  Zooming in on a log axis like that can be awkward since the ticks are so much more compressed on the negative side compared to the positive.

Comment: Maybe my version of Python is too old. I get `AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'locator_params` when I use that.

Comment: by `ax` I mean the current `Axis` object, which you were getting at via `gca`.

Comment: Yes sorry I misunderstood. I tried that, but the y-axis still looks exactly the same.

Comment: Ah!  Okay I misunderstood as well.  Let me edit in what's going on.

Comment: Is the `ax` in `ax.get_major_formatter()` also supposed to be replaced with `f.gca()`? When I do that, I get another attribute error.